# How to configure MySQL with CSV Storage Engine?

Tags: mysql, windows, csv

How do I configure MySQL on Windows to use the CSV Storage Engine.

I read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html) about using this configuration option:

```
  --with-csv-storage-engine
```

However, it doesn't say how or where to use that option. For example, does it go into one of the INI files? Does MySQL have to be reinstalled or can it just be reconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose engine at the time of table creation if your mysql version support that engine-

Just do like below-

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
id INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = CSV;
```

**Update:**

Normally we don't need csv as default storage engine, so wherever required we can create table with CSV engine. But if you want then you can do as per below-

**You can set default storage engine in your session and for this there is no requirement of mysql service restart:**

```
SET SET default_storage_engine='CSV';

CREATE TABLE csvtest
(
id INT NOT NULL
);
```

**Another way is that you can update default storage engine in your my.cnf/my.ini file but for this you need to restart mysql service:**

Add below line in your conf file:

```
default_storage_engine='CSV';
```

Now restart mysql service and you can simply create table with csv engine without mentioning it.

```
CREATE TABLE csvtest
(
id INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick. Although I am not sure what the difference is between this and simply exporting as a CSV?

Comment: Thanks.  Can you think of any advantages to using the CSV engine? I think I read somewhere that it had been deprecated.

Comment: Its advantage is that you can simply export it and import in any type of db either mysql, mssql, oracle etc even without any specific tool and expertise as all db support to csv format as it is a text  file...and obviously it is light with low overhead...need low server resources.....but with very less features like innodb or any other engine.....its good to store logs etc as mysql itself used it for logging point of view to store slowlogs and general logs if you want to store your logs in table istead of file, which is managed by log_output variable.